# If a vector "x" is a subset of a vector df$y, df a dataframe which consists of: "y" and frequencies "fy", can I get a df of "x" and "fx" ? [ R ]

Tags: r, dataframe

If `list_a` is a subset of `df$list_b`, where `df$frequency_b` are the frequencies of the values in `df$list_b`, I would like to create a data frame where I want the list_a with the corresponding frequencies, thus a data frame `[df1$list_a,df1$frequency_a]` . (NOTE: all the elements in `list_a` are in `df$list_b`).

Example:

```
list_a <- c("John","George","Jack","Kathrine")
df$list_b <- c("Mario","Jack","Ana","George","Loizos",
          "Kathrine","John","Jack","Yannis")
```

where,

```
df$frequency_b <- c("10","3","15","23","13","50","553","334","332")
```

I want a data frame such as:

```
df1$list_a <- c("John","George","Jack","Kathrine")
```

and the corresponding frequencies:

```
df1$frequencies <- c(553,3,15,23)
```

Is there any way to implement this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the `%in%` operator to subset the names in the original data frame.

```
> list_a <- c("John","George","Jack","Kathrine")
> list_b <- c("Mario","Jack","Ana","George","Loizos",
+                "Kathrine","John","Jack","Yannis")
> frequency_b <- c("10","3","15","23","13","50","553","334","332")
> df <- data.frame(name=list_b, count=frequency_b)
> df1 <- df[df$name %in% list_a,]
> df1
      name count
2     Jack     3
4   George    23
6 Kathrine    50
7     John   553
8     Jack   334
```

Note that there were two people named Jack in your data, so the output data frame has 5 rows, not 4 as in your original post.

regards,

Len